# Inflation TIPS - What does it mean - 10Y breakeven shorts with 0.8 beta?

Tags: inflation, treasuries

"10Y breakeven shorts with 0.8 beta"

"10Y breakeven shorts with long 80% nominal to eliminate long duration bias"

Are the above two the same, what do they mean?

Comment: "breakeven long": you are long TIPS and short nominal Treasuries, you profit if the breakeven inflation rate increases (hence the name). "breakeven short": you are short TIPS and long nominal treasuries. 0.8 or 80% refers to how much of the nominal bonds you have for each TIPS.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Alex for the explanation.